# Secure a string in PHP

Tags: php, security

What do you think it's the best method to secure a string in PHP? I speak of hiding its content and avoid malicious changes by the user.

We can use the open_ssl functions, but I prefer using a simpler solution, more platform-compatible, quicker, and without the need of public/private keys.

For example, it can be useful to save the login token in a cookie, or for creating the return URL of a payment system, where we need to know the bought item ID but it cannot be known by the user.

I think that this can be accomplished using some obfuscation method (like char replacement using a dictionary), and a trailing hash to ensure the data integrity, but I would like to hear your opinions.

Thank you

Comment: This might be better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Since "secure a string" is extremely vague and broad, let's go with the more concrete scenarios you hint at like a login token in a cookie or a token in a URL: if these tokens are pseudo random values, there's no need to "secure" them any further. Think about it. You generate a pseudo-random value which in and of itself has no meaning whatsoever. It only has a meaning in that there's some data connected with it on the server. If the user knows the token, it identifies and connects him with that data. If he alters the token, it becomes meaningless. Guessing a random token is infeasible if the token is long and random enough and expires within a relatively short amount of time.

If you were to encrypt this token using some function, it simply becomes another token with exactly the same properties as the first one. It's still a blob of pseudo random data which has no meaning in and of itself. Nothing gained, nothing lost. Even adding something like a MAC to the token is hardly worthwhile, in the end you'll just end up with a longer blob of pseudo-random data.

The security of a *token* already comes from its meaninglessness, length and entropy. Encryption will not enhance that any further.

Comment: Ok, but what about the second scenario? A return URL with an string that contains the bought ID but not visible to the user?

Comment: Use a token as well. Never give any meaningful data that the user could alter to the user. Save all sensitive data server side and give the user a token which refers to that data. Or if you *do* need to hand out actual ids for whatever reason, have a way that you can verify on the server whether the user is supposed to have that id or not.